# How to write the iterator in v-for as a string in v-if?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to understand how to use v-for with v-if's to write repetitive teasers without more simple vue-logic. Now it seems, when using v-for with v-if within, it is not possible to write the index number to each teaser to select the corresponding values.

I want to replace the "1" in the below example with "{{ n }}" in the v-if statement. How is that possible?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  title: string,
  icon1?: string, // possible values: 'sun', 'moon' or 'misc'
  textBefore1: string,
  textColor1?: string,
  textAfter1?: string,
  icon2?: string, // possible values: 'sun', 'moon' or 'misc'
  textBefore2: string,
  textColor2?: string,
  textAfter2?: string,
  icon3?: string, // possible values: 'sun', 'moon' or 'misc'
  textBefore3: string,
  textColor3?: string,
  textAfter3?: string,
  icon4?: string, // possible values: 'sun', 'moon' or 'misc'
  textBefore4: string,
  textColor4?: string,
  textAfter4?: string,
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <div class="teaserContent">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="positioning--top">
        <div class="titleContainer">
          <h2 class="title">{{ title }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="positioningBottom">

        <div v-for="n in 4" class="cardElement">
          <!-- Repeat the teaser 4 times and replace the number with the index "n" -->
          <div class="iconContainer">
            <span v-if="icon1 === 'sun' || icon1 === 'moon' || icon1 === 'misc'" class="material-symbols-rounded icon">{{ icon1 === 'sun' ? 'sunny' : icon1 === 'moon' ? 'clear_night' : icon1 === 'misc' ? 'brightness_4' : 'clear_night' }}</span>
            <span v-else class="material-symbols-rounded icon">clear_night</span>
          </div>
          <div class="textContainer">
            <span class="text text--before">{{ textBefore1 }}</span>
            <span v-if="textColor1" class="text text--color">{{ ' ' + textColor1 }}</span>
            <span v-if="textAfter1" class="text text--after">{{ ' ' + textAfter1 }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
// style here ...
</style>
```

## Edit: Added the working Solution

thanks to [Keyboard Corporation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21370707/keyboard-corporation)

CardTeaser.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type {ICardTeaser} from "@/components/CardTeaser/CardTeaser.types";

interface Props {
  title: string,
  teasers: Array<ICardTeaser>,
}

const props = defineProps<Props>();

const getIcon = (icon: ICardTeaser["icon"]) => {
  if (icon === 'sun') {return 'sunny';}
  if (icon === 'misc') {return 'brightness_4';}
  return 'clear_night';
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="teaserContent">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="positioning--top">
        <div class="titleContainer">
          <h2 class="title">{{ title }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="positioningBottom">
        <div v-for="(teaser, n) in props.teasers" v-bind:key="`cardElement-${n}`" class="cardElement">
          <div class="iconContainer">
            <span class="material-symbols-rounded icon">{{ getIcon(teaser.icon) }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="textContainer">
            <span class="text text--before">{{ teaser.textBefore }}</span>
            <span v-if="teaser.textColor" class="text text--color">{{ ' ' + teaser.textColor }}</span>
            <span v-if="teaser.textAfter" class="text text--after">{{ ' ' + teaser.textAfter }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
// Styles here ...
</style>
```

CardTeaser.types.ts:

```
export interface ICardTeaser {
    textBefore: string;
    textColor?: string;
    textAfter?: string;
    icon?: 'sun' | 'moon' | 'misc';
}
```

Implementation of the Template with data:

```
<CardTeaser title="Card Teaser" :teasers="[
  {
    textBefore: 'Card 1',
    textColor: 'in color',
    textAfter: 'with more text',
    icon: 'sun',
  },
  {
    textBefore: 'Card 2',
    textColor: 'also in Color',
    icon: 'moon',
  },
  {
    textBefore: 'Card 3',
    textColor: 'in color',
    textAfter: 'and more text',
    icon: 'misc',
  },
  {
    textBefore: 'Card 4',
    textColor: 'with more color',
    textAfter: 'and other text',
  }
]"/>
```

(seems I could also do a smaller Template for each card and just put those within a CardTeaserContainer or somehting.)

Comment: You could put all the icons in an array: `icons = [icon1, icon2,...]`. Then in your v-if you could do: `< span v-if="icons[n+1]== ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly use the iterator variable n from v-for inside v-if as a string, but you can do this by creating a `computed` property that returns the correct prop based on the index.

First, define your props as an array of objects:

```
defineProps({
 teasers: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
 },
})
```

Each object in the `teasers` should have the properties `icon`, `textBefore`, `textColor` and `textAfter`.

Then, in your template, you use `v-for` to iterate over the `teasers`:

```
<div v-for="(teaser, n) in teasers" class="cardElement">
 <div class="iconContainer">
    <span v-if="teaser.icon === 'sun' || teaser.icon === 'moon' || teaser.icon === 'misc'" class="material-symbols-rounded icon">{{ teaser.icon === 'sun' ? 'sunny' : teaser.icon === 'moon' ? 'clear_night' : teaser.icon === 'misc' ? 'brightness_4' : 'clear_night' }}</span>
    <span v-else class="material-symbols-rounded icon">clear_night</span>
 </div>
 <div class="textContainer">
    <span class="text text--before">{{ teaser.textBefore }}</span>
    <span v-if="teaser.textColor" class="text text--color">{{ ' ' + teaser.textColor }}</span>
    <span v-if="teaser.textAfter" class="text text--after">{{ ' ' + teaser.textAfter }}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Keyboard Corporation. I'll add the code of my final solution to my answer.